# Json format for jqgrid

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

how would i remove the first "{" and last "}" in my json object?

```
{
  [{
    "idroutes": "73",
    "idstops": "97",
    "bodyno": "UWN237",
    "eta": "2015-01-08 20:29:13",
    "sequence_number": "0",
    "device_id": "861074027368953",
    "duration": "1.13",
    "duration_from_origin": "1.13"
  }, {
    "idroutes": "73",
    "idstops": "104",
    "bodyno": "UWN237",
    "eta": "2015-01-08 20:40:13",
    "sequence_number": "1",
    "device_id": "861074027368953",
    "duration": "10.92",
    "duration_from_origin": "12.05"
  }, {
    "idroutes": "73",
    "idstops": "100",
    "bodyno": "UWN237",
    "eta": "2015-01-08 20:44:13",
    "sequence_number": "2",
    "device_id": "861074027368953",
    "duration": "4.44",
    "duration_from_origin": "16.49"
  }, {
    "idroutes": "73",
    "idstops": "99",
    "bodyno": "UWN237",
    "eta": "2015-01-08 20:48:13",
    "sequence_number": "3",
    "device_id": "861074027368953",
    "duration": "3.36",
    "duration_from_origin": "19.85"
  }, {
    "idroutes": "73",
    "idstops": "101",
    "bodyno": "UWN237",
    "eta": "2015-01-08 20:53:13",
    "sequence_number": "4",
    "device_id": "861074027368953",
    "duration": "4.92",
    "duration_from_origin": "24.77"
  }, {
    "idroutes": "73",
    "idstops": "102",
    "bodyno": "UWN237",
    "eta": "2015-01-08 20:59:13",
    "sequence_number": "5",
    "device_id": "861074027368953",
    "duration": "6.36",
    "duration_from_origin": "31.13"
  }, {
    "idroutes": "73",
    "idstops": "93",
    "bodyno": "UWN237",
    "eta": "2015-01-08 21:08:13",
    "sequence_number": "6",
    "device_id": "861074027368953",
    "duration": "8.4",
    "duration_from_origin": "39.53"
  }, {
    "idroutes": "73",
    "idstops": "95",
    "bodyno": "UWN237",
    "eta": "2015-01-08 21:12:13",
    "sequence_number": "7",
    "device_id": "861074027368953",
    "duration": "4.2",
    "duration_from_origin": "43.73"
  }, {
    "idroutes": "73",
    "idstops": "94",
    "bodyno": "UWN237",
    "eta": "2015-01-08 21:15:13",
    "sequence_number": "8",
    "device_id": "861074027368953",
    "duration": "2.88",
    "duration_from_origin": "46.61"
  }, {
    "idroutes": "73",
    "idstops": "96",
    "bodyno": "UWN237",
    "eta": "2015-01-08 21:23:13",
    "sequence_number": "9",
    "device_id": "861074027368953",
    "duration": "8.88",
    "duration_from_origin": "55.49"
  }]
}
```

btw, those data comes from an API i have called and wanted it to be displayed in jqgrid. i tried to copy the result then store it in a variable but still, nothing happens. but when i tried removing the first and last curly brackets, the result was fine. just wonderin why this happen and how to remove those

Comment: is this a json object or a string?

Comment: They invalidate the JSON. Where do they come from?

Answer (score 0):

The input data are incorrect. It's invalid for the point of view JSON format. You can validate the data [here](http://jsonlint.org/) for example. The outer object `{}` have to contains properties, but you include `[]` **without specifying the corresponding property name**, like `{ "rows": []}`.

So to make the input data valid JSON data you should do remove the outer brackets `{}` or to add the name of the property (for example `"rows":`) before the opening inner bracket `[`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of wrong json format.

If you start from  "{" means its a json object which has key and its value.

If you start from  "[" means its a array format which doesn’t need key pair,its just array of value, or json object.

There are 2 solution

1) you should give key value for getting array of json as per your data.

2) you should fetch only json array from your API,

Currently you are putting your json array into json.

Comment: I now have added a key value,  
{"NewDataSet":[]}

Comment: Then you can get Json array as a value with using "NewDataSet" key.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is returned as a string you can easily parse it using `JSON.parse` by taking substring of the actual string -

```js
var a ='{[{ "idroutes": "73", "idstops": "97", "bodyno": "UWN237", "eta": "2015-01-08 20:29:13", "sequence_number": "0", "device_id": "861074027368953", "duration": "1.13", "duration_from_origin": "1.13" }, { "idroutes": "73", "idstops": "104", "bodyno": "UWN237", "eta": "2015-01-08 20:40:13", "sequence_number": "1", "device_id": "861074027368953", "duration": "10.92", "duration_from_origin": "12.05" }, { "idroutes": "73", "idstops": "100", "bodyno": "UWN237", "eta": "2015-01-08 20:44:13", "sequence_number": "2", "device_id": "861074027368953", "duration": "4.44", "duration_from_origin": "16.49" }, { "idroutes": "73", "idstops": "99", "bodyno": "UWN237", "eta": "2015-01-08 20:48:13", "sequence_number": "3", "device_id": "861074027368953", "duration": "3.36", "duration_from_origin": "19.85" }, { "idroutes": "73", "idstops": "101", "bodyno": "UWN237", "eta": "2015-01-08 20:53:13", "sequence_number": "4", "device_id": "861074027368953", "duration": "4.92", "duration_from_origin": "24.77" }, { "idroutes": "73", "idstops": "102", "bodyno": "UWN237", "eta": "2015-01-08 20:59:13", "sequence_number": "5", "device_id": "861074027368953", "duration": "6.36", "duration_from_origin": "31.13" }, { "idroutes": "73", "idstops": "93", "bodyno": "UWN237", "eta": "2015-01-08 21:08:13", "sequence_number": "6", "device_id": "861074027368953", "duration": "8.4", "duration_from_origin": "39.53" }, { "idroutes": "73", "idstops": "95", "bodyno": "UWN237", "eta": "2015-01-08 21:12:13", "sequence_number": "7", "device_id": "861074027368953", "duration": "4.2", "duration_from_origin": "43.73" }, { "idroutes": "73", "idstops": "94", "bodyno": "UWN237", "eta": "2015-01-08 21:15:13", "sequence_number": "8", "device_id": "861074027368953", "duration": "2.88", "duration_from_origin": "46.61" }, { "idroutes": "73", "idstops": "96", "bodyno": "UWN237", "eta": "2015-01-08 21:23:13", "sequence_number": "9", "device_id": "861074027368953", "duration": "8.88", "duration_from_origin": "55.49" }]}';

console.dir(JSON.parse(a.substring(1,a.length-1)));
```